# setSelectedIndex in material io

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-ui

I'm trying to modify select-menus to change the selected index:

```
 let filterField= mdc.select.MDCSelect.attachTo(
        document.querySelector(".mdc-select--location")
    );
```

This is how im attaching MDCSelect to a given field and later on i'm trying to set the selectedIndex:

```
filterField.setSelectedIndex(1);
```

But i get an error with

```
setSelectedIndex is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit old question, but I'll leave the answer to help someone who may need...

According to mdc-select API, you should use the property "selectedIndex", not the function "setSelectedIndex()".
Link: [mdc-select API](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-select#mdcselect-api)

But if you're using it within any Web Framework, such as React or Angular, then the function "setSelectedIndex()" can be used.
[Within Web Framework](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-select#usage-within-web-frameworks)